# Disadvantages of First-class functions

Tags: function

Are there any disadvantages to having [first class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) in a language?

Joel in this [entry](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html) says

> Object-oriented programming languages aren't completely convinced that
>   you should be allowed to do anything with functions.

I might be naïve here, but why don’t all languages support first class functions if there aren’t much issues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an ideal world where there was never a cost associated with developing new features, the only downside I can see to including functional programming techniques would be confusion to developers who are not familiar with functional techniques (and I don't really see that as much of a downside).

In reality, treating functions as first-class typically requires significant rewrites to the compiler itself.  The cost of doing this has to be weighed against the long-term gain.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this feature might be a disadvantage if introducing the change requires a costly re-write of language compilers, interpreters, and other tools. It might also be a disadvantage if the language's culture is not familiar enough with the advantages provided by this feature in which case adding the feature is a waste of effort.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, first class functions require runtime interpretation of code and some form of garbage collection. Both of these add overhead that might not be suitable for certain problems and languages.

Comment: Not necessarily. There are languages with first class functions which aren't interpreted and don't have GC (f.e. C++). Closures are more difficult to implement without GC though.